# Keep dynamic table synced with model in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, data-binding, binding, model, html-table

I have the following sample model:

```
{
 a:{
    x:0,
    z:0,
    f:1
   },
 b:{
   x:"a",
   u:"b"
   }
}
```

Which I render into two different tables

```
 <div class="col-sm-5">
                <h1>A</h1>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Key</th>
                        <th>Value</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr ng-repeat="(key,value) in schema.a">
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" ng-model="key" required>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" ng-model="value" required>
                        </td>
                        <td></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-5 col-md-offset-2">
                <h1>B</h1>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Key</th>
                        <th>Value</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr ng-repeat="(key,value) in schema.b">
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" ng-model="key" required>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" ng-model="value" required>
                        </td>
                        <td></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
```

The tables are dynamic, which means I can add new rows to it.

Now when I change any values inside the table, **they aren´t synchronized with the model -> Editing not possible**

- What do I need to do to store changes automatically in the original
  model?
- If this is not possible, how can I get a Json Schema from my table
  like the one the tables are rendered from, so that I only have to
  overwrite the old one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off you can't dynamically change an object property name or `key`. So what you are trying to do with `ng-model="key"` simply won't work.

As far as the `value` part you should be using the object reference in your `ng-model`

```
<tr ng-repeat="(key,value) in schema.b">
    <td>{{key}}</td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" ng-model="schema.b[key]" required>
    </td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
```

if you need to be able to edit the `key` then you need to change your data structure to an array of objects with each object having the same property names for keys

Comment: thank you. Now I´ve disabled the key editing so that the user has to set it when creating